# How to get and store the console logged value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, console

I am trying to get the console logged value

here is the code,

```
console.log('sample output');
var logBackup = console.log;
var logMessages = [];

console.log = function () {
  logMessages.push.apply(logMessages, arguments);
  logBackup.apply(console, arguments);
};

console.log('logged values here', logMessages);
```

but it's returning a recursion empty arrays,

[image]

is there any way to get the console logged value and display that on webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Just a quick hack but the key is that I check that I don't add a reference of `logMessages` into `logMessages` itself, avoiding the circular reference.

```js
console.log('sample output');
var logBackup = console.log;
var logMessages = [];

console.log = function (...argz) {
  pushArgz = argz.filter(a => a !== logMessages);
  logMessages.push(...pushArgz);
  logBackup.apply(console, argz);
};

console.log('logged values here', logMessages);
console.log('logged values here', logMessages);
console.log('logged values here', logMessages);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its working fine, right now we are getting the existing console data, is there anyway to get the upcoming console data and listen to the console continuously.